# Update zip file in S3 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I have a java application in which I would like to process around 10GB records of file and zip them to a single folder and upload to S3. Since the overall size is around 10GB I cannot add all the files in memory and then upload to S3, and hence I would need to create a zip file in S3 and update the contents of the zip file by partitioning my files. Is there any means by which I can update an existing zip file in S3 without downloading to my local folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aws java sdk for it

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.398</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a amazon s3 client using following

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key"); 
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
```

Create a TransferManager and set the MultipartUploadThresholdoad.
Amazon S3 impose minimum part size of 5mb, So we are using 5mb here. You can increase the size as per your requirement.

```
TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
  .withS3Client(amazonS3)
  .withMultipartUploadThreshold((long) (5 * 1024 * 1024))
  .build();
```

Set yours S3 bucket name where you want to upload and keyName will used to name the uploaded file. tm.upload will start the uploading process in background.

```
String bucketName = "my-bucket";
String keyName = "mydata.zip";
File file = new File("path_to_file/mydata.zip");
Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, file);
```

waitForCompletion is the blocking call and will return result once function completes its execution to upload file to s3.

```
try {
    upload.waitForCompletion();
} catch (AmazonClientException e) {
    // ...
}
```